# Problema con consulta mysql, filtro where

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: Alguien sabe por que razon la ultima consulta MysQL no muestra el registro NULL de danielad?, se supone que al hacer el filtro NULL sobre el campo asignacion deberia mostrarme todos los que concuerdan, pero en este caso no]

Sera algun error de mysql?

mysql> select usuario_ad, nombre, asignacion from usuarios where asignacion='NULL';

Alguien sabe por que razon la ultima consulta MysQL no muestra el registro NULL de danielad?, se supone que al hacer el filtro NULL sobre el campo asignacion deberia mostrarme todos los que concuerdan, pero en este caso no

Comment: ¿Será que el `NULL` de daniela fue tomado como valor por defecto y los otros fueron escritos *a mano*?  Convendría que muestres el resultado de un `SHOW CREATE TABLE usuarios`. Pon el texto, no una captura de pantalla. Si lo que quieres es que cuando no se escriba nada en ese campo adquiera por defecto el valor `NULL`, lo puedes indicar en la constitución de la tabla, haciendo que esa columna acepte nulos y que su valor por defecto sea `NULL`. No tienes que hacer nada más, aparte de normalizar los que hayas escrito *a mano*, borrando de ellos la **palabra** `NULL`.

Comment: https://es.imgbb.com   aca esta lo que me muestra, y es correcto, yo actualice los valores NULL manualmente, no se si pueda actualizar con el valor orginal.

Comment: No agregues el contenido en enlaces externos, además, no sale nada en el enlace. Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/212543/edit)  agregando todo lo que sea necesario para poder ayudar a resolver el problema. Tu comentario, no lo entiendo del todo. No se trata de actualizar los valores `NULL` manualmente, sino de borrarlos y hacer que esa columna acepte `NULL` por defecto, no es lo mismo ni es igual.

Comment: Por favor, en vez de una imagen pon el texto que ha generado el `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Es mucho mejor tener el texto simplemente que no una imagen, la cual es difícil de ver en dispositivos pequeños.

Comment: Segun veo no es lo mismo actualizar NULL en una consulta que el NULL que pone la tabla por defecto, mi pregunta es.. si es posible ponerle null de nuevo pero como lo hace mysql con su formato original

Comment: Sí, claro que es posible. Para los datos que ya existen, sólo tienes que **borrar la palabra `NULL` escrita a mano**, dejarlo en blanco, sin nada escrito, ni espacio ni nada. Si observas el `CREATE TABLE`, la columna adquirirá `NULL` por defecto. Y para futuras inserciones, puedes omitir el valor a la hora de insertar, o mandarle `NULL` así tal cual, sin comillas ni nada.

Comment: Correcto A. Cedano, esa era la solucion, actualizar NULL sin comillas, ahora todo concuerda, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

creo que debes probar lo siguiente:

```
select usuario_ad, nombre, asignacion from usuarios where asignacion is null;
```

Comment: Excelente, me trae el registro, pero solo trae este    usuario_ad | nombre | asignacion |
+------------+--------+------------+
| danielad   | valery | NULL       |
+------------+--------+------------+    se supone que deberia traer tambien a andres, Karen, marisol, caro

Comment: Creo saber el problema... sabes como puedo actualizar un campo para que  quede NULL, es de decir where asignacion='NULL', si lo hago asi mysql lo hace pero es como si cambiara el formato original a como cuando la tabla lo crea automaticamente

Comment: puedes usar por ejemplo:   update usuario set asignacion = null where usuario_ad ='angelicaad' and nombre='andres';